# « cracher dans des langues »

Tags: québec

Extrait d'une [interview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8Df5N9lZo8#t=7m18) de Céline Dion, à propos de ses enfants :

> Parce que deux jumeaux qui **crachent dans des langues**, là, et pis qu'écoutent « I am a gummy bear, I am a gummy bear », « Peanut Butter Jelly, Peanut Butter Jelly » [...]

Est-ce que cette expression est compréhensible pour un québecois ? (je ne la trouve pas sur Google, donc si c'est une expression elle ne doit pas être courante)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« Cracher dans des langues » n'est pas une expression. Ça ne veut rien dire du tout. Ce n'est d'ailleurs pas ce que Céline Dion dit dans cet extrait. Elle dit :

> Parce que deux jumeaux qui **crient à** [la] **journée longue**, là, et pis qu'écoutent « I am a gummy bear, I am a gummy bear », « Peanut Butter Jelly, Peanut Butter Jelly » [...]

Bref, elle explique que les jumeaux font du grabuge toute la journée et que cela irrite parfois son aîné.

Comment: Merci, je n'aurais jamais pu trouver ça :-)